# How can I pass filenames with spaces as arguments?

Tags: command-line, bash, python

I have a Python script which accepts string arguments.

```
$ python script.py "one image.jpg" "another image.jpg"
```

This works as expected.

Python argparse: `["one image.jpg", "another image.jpg"]`

---

If I need to pass filenames I would do,

```
$ python script.py $(ls "/some/dir/*.jpg")
```

Python argparse: `["one", "image.jpg", "another", "image.jpg"]`

If use the `-Q` of `ls` command, I can wrap results between double quotes. However, quotes stay escaped in Python script, ie.

```
$ python script.py $(ls -Q "/some/dir/*.jpg")
```

Python argparse: `['"one image.jpg"', '"another image.jpg"']`

---

How should I expand `ls` filenames into proper strings to use as arguments? (as in my very first example)

Comment: You should quote the shell expansion: `"$(ls -Q '/some/dir/*.jpg')"`. However there are better alternatives as stated by the answers.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Don't parse `ls`.  Just use:

```
python script.py /path/to/*.jpg
```

This performs shell globbing which replaces `/path/to/*.jpg` by the proper list.

Answer (score 6):

I think the glob answer above is best, but `xargs` and `find` is also a solution that can be used sometimes.

```
find /some/dir/ -name '*.jpg' -print0 | xargs -0 python script.py
```

This works because `-print0` on `find` will separate the output with null bytes rather than spaces, and the `-0` on the xargs command line will assume the input is separated by null bytes.